# Smallest VS fewest

Tags: superlatives

Are both equivalent?

I ask this because in my language both translate as the same thing. Could someone explain their use?

> We have the smallest customer queue.

> We have the fewest customer queue.

THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same. The first one is correct, and the second one is bad grammar.

"Fewest" is always a quantifier that means "smallest in number", whereas "smallest" is always an adjective that means "smallest in size". I don't believe the two words can ever have the same meaning.

Quantifiers that signify a plural quantity are followed by a plural noun. But "customer queue" is singular. This means, "fewest" is being incorrectly used as an adjective to modify "customer queue".

"*We have the fewest customer queue**s***" would be grammatically correct, but has quite a different meaning to your first sentence.

Comment: Go, could you contrast the difference between a quantifier and an adjective? I tried, but couldn't understand where you want to get.

Comment: As far as I know, both quantifiers and adjectives come before a noun (Q+N) or an adjective and a noun (Q+A+N).

Comment: Quantifiers that signify a plural quantity are followed by a plural noun. But "customer queue" is singular. "*We have the fewest customer queue**s***" is grammatically correct, but has a different meaning to your first sentence.

Comment: "Fewest" always means "smallest in number", whereas "smallest" always means "smallest in size". I don't believe the two words can never have the same meaning.

Comment: You are a priceless gem, GO. ahaha. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: You could also say "We are in the queue with the fewest customers",

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes. Thanks ;)